# From Freeswitch CHANNEL_HANGUP events determine which part has disconnected a call

Tags: freeswitch

Is it possible from FreeSWITCH CHANNEL_HANGUP event (or others) determine who has disconnected a call?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by inspecting the following SIP header - 'sip_hangup_disposition'

Link to the corresponding documentation https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/sip_hangup_disposition